# The usual answer not helping with TypeError

Tags: python, list

I'm getting a `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable` but I can't see where the usual answer of use `list[]` instead of `list()` applies. I don't seem to be using either notation, just calling functions on the list. I'm quite stuck and could use some help here

```
import scheduler

def main():
    sched = scheduler.Scheduler()

    sched.line_list("/home/scabandari/Desktop/threads.txt")  # Error is caused by this line

    # sched.create_processList()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

scheduler.py:

```
import process


class Scheduler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.line_list = []
        self.process_list = []
        pass

    # populates line_list[] from "/location/.txt" file, each line reps a process object
    def line_list(self, file):
        f = open(file)
        getlines = f.readlines()
        for line in getlines:
            self.line_list.append(line)
        self.line_list.pop(0)

    # populates process_list[] from line_list[]
    def process_list(self):
        for line in self.line_list:
            temp_arr = line.split()
            self.process_list.append(process.Process(temp_arr[0], temp_arr[1],
                                     temp_arr[2], temp_arr[3]))

        for proc in self.process_list:
            proc.print_process()
```

Comment: What's the full error message?

Comment: You need to decide whether you want `line_list` to be a method or a list. It can't be both.

Comment: `self.line_list = []` ... `sched.line_list(...)`  the method `line_list` isn't accesable if you make an attribute of the same name.

Comment: Your code is far from minimal. It can be reduced to: http://ideone.com/GoQQpD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Know that when you define your class object named `Scheduler` as follows

```
class Scheduler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.line_list = []
        self.process_list = []

    def line_list(self, file):
        f = open(file)
        getlines = f.readlines()
        for line in getlines:
            self.line_list.append(line)
        self.line_list.pop(0)        
    ...
```

and then instantiate it, i.e.

```
inst = Scheduler()
```

the definition you have done of your method `line_list`, is overriden by the post-instantiation execution of `__init__`, which turns it into a list.

Which means that, as melpomene mentions in comments,

> you need to decide whether you want `line_list` to be a method or a list. It can't be both.

Thus, what you may want to do is renaming your method, furthermore giving it a name representative of what it actually does, e.g.

```
    ...
    def populate_line_list(self, file):
        '''
        Method which populates line_list from "/location/.txt" file,
        each line reps a process object
        '''
        f = open(file)
        getlines = f.readlines()
        for line in getlines:
            self.line_list.append(line)
        self.line_list.pop(0)
        f.close() #do not forget to close your file, or use a with-statement
    ...
```

Finally you will be able to do

```
import scheduler

def main():
    sched = scheduler.Scheduler()
    sched.populate_line_list("/home/scabandari/Desktop/threads.txt")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks @Kanak for the explanation! This solved my problem